# Linq a una Clase con List<Class>

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una duda, yo soy un poco nuevo en esto de Linq, y necesito de su ayuda.

```
public class getHistorialInstalaciones
    {
        public string end_date { get; set; }
        public udataHistorialInteracciones udata { get; set; }
        public fromHistorialInteracciones from { get; set; }
        public List<toHistorialInteracciones> to { get; set; }
    }
```

Y quiero hacer una consulta con Linq que la hago asi
Casos = a la Deserializacion en Json a la Clase.

```
var Lista = (from r in casos
             select new
                 {
                     //toI = r.udata.To,
                     //toII = r.to,
                     //fromI = r.@from.address,
                     end_dateI = r.end_date,
                 }).ToList();
```

Pero necesito también traerme el valor de `to`, `from` y `udata.to`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer la consulta de esos campos?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que `casos` es de tipo `List<getHistorialInstalaciones>` solo debes poner a qué tipo deseas que se agregue ese objeto, en est caso `select new getHistorialInstalaciones { ... }`:

```
var Lista = (from r in casos
    select new getHistorialInstalaciones
    {
         to = r.udata.To, // también puede ser "to = r.To", depende del que necesites
         fromI = r.@from.address,
         end_date = r.end_date,
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo intente como me dices, pero no me funciono... Me dice que {"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."} con to y from...

Answer (score 0):

Porque necesitas realizar un linq que transforme los datos si podrias usar la `JsonProperty` para indicar un campo que sea diferente al de json.

Si usas [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/) podrias implementar

```
public class getHistorialInstalaciones
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "end_date")]
    public string end_dateI  { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "udata")]
    public udataHistorialInteracciones toI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "from")]
    public fromHistorialInteracciones fromI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "to")]
    public List<toHistorialInteracciones> toII { get; set; }
}
```

entonces cuando deserialices mapeara con las propeidades del json property pero tu clase tendra las que tu definas, de esta forma no necesitas convertir

[.Net NewtonSoft Json Deserialize map to a different property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, estoy ocupando Newtonsoft.Json, y con eso los Deserializo a una clase. y la verdad estoy aprendiendo a usar Json en C#.